# Most efficient way to handle multiple descendant selectors?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a site that has two sections; a largely static side that uses intricate designs with coloured backgrounds, and a dynamic blog that simply uses a white background.

I've specified in my _settings.scss (Foundation 5) file to use a dark text on white background for all text elements. This is working without issue, and applies to the blog and static side perfectly.

Where I am stumbling is finding an efficient way to manage the different coloured backgrounds and appropriate text styles for each background on the static side.

I have a "dark" & "light" section that use a dark and light blue background respectively, alternating down the page.

I have thus far been using each as a class name that acts as a wrapper around my content. i.e.

```
<div class="dark section"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="small-8 columns (etc.)>
      <h1> Some Header </h1>
      <p> Some text </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="light section"> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="small-8 columns (etc.)>
      <h1> Some Header </h1>
      <p> Some text </p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

That's my HTML. The text (p) is white for both, and I have no issues styling that (overriding _settings.scss). It's the headers that are giving me issue. I am struggling to find a method of targeting the headers in each coloured section without it spilling to the next, alternate coloured section; or without adding numerous classes to each and every instance of the header dependant on background colour.

Thus far I have been using: (colours simplified as I'm using SCSS variables)

```
.dark {
   background-color: dark-blue;
   colour: white;
}

.dark h1,h2 {
  colour: orange;
}

.light {
   background-color: light-blue;
   colour: white;
}

.light h1,h2 {
  colour: dark-blue;
}

.section {
 *insert various padding here*
}
```

Now this to my mind, should work. However, I'm having the styles from the `light` class override the styles (where different) in the `dark` class. i.e. The dark sections have dark-blue headers, rather than orange. I can't seem to stop the selector from riding from one 'section' to another through the cascade.

I've probably made a stupidly simple oversight, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the descendant selector:

```
.dark h1 {
    color: orange;
}
```

Here we have selected a class (`.dark`), and then selected an `h1` that is a child *at any level* to the selected class. So this will apply to **any** `<h1>` elements *within your* `<div class="dark section">` *element*, no matter what level.

If you want to use this descendant selector with multiple elements, you'll need to add the class to each side of the comma. Currently your selection of `.dark h1, h2` is selecting all `h1` elements that are children of class .`dark` (as I've explained above), **and** all `h2` elements *anywhere in your body*, period... and likewise for `.light`. **What you need is:**

```
.dark h1, .dark h2 {
    color: orange;
}

.light h1, .light h2 {
    color: dark-blue;
}
```

Note that with your original code above, you are typing `colour` instead of `color`. The spec uses American English, so you'll need to fix these unless you have renamed them as variables or something using your pre-processor. Also note that you haven't added a closing `"` to your "small-8" class names.

Comment: Ah you beat me to it by 12 seconds!

Comment: @Aibrean I saw that! It's happened to me before countless times with BoltClock... watch out for him ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I was unaware of the requirement for .light or .dark each time an element was selected. As for the rest such as "colour" and closing-", I was just suffering auto-correct and typos. Problem solved! Cheers!